# Cannot write to Postgres database in Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I am trying to manually run a SQL script to create some tables and insert some data on my recently created Heroku instance, database is Postgres, when running I get the error

```
ERROR:  permission denied to create database
```

To connect I am running the following which is all taken from my `DATABASE_URL` variable.

```
heroku run psql -h myhost -p port -d database -U user -f ./sql/daily_fixtures.sql
```

How can I deal with this?

Comment: is "user" the actual PostgreSQL username ?

Comment: Yes, it’s the username taken from the DATABASE_URL

Comment: What about heroku pg:psql ? Did you check https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql ? In particular the "Using the CLI" paragraph ?

Comment: It looks like your `daily_fixtures.sql` file contains at least one `CREATE DATABASE` statement. You can't do that on Heroku—it creates a database for you and you can fill it up.

Comment: Thanks Chris, it was exactly that